# Macro for converting IST to AEST

Tags: vba, excel

I have column of Indian Standard Time in Excel that has to be converted into Australian Eastern Standard Time using VBA

In Excel it is very simple as:

If B Column has IST and I need AEST in C Column then C = B + "4:30"
 but I cannot able to use same formula in my macro.

I will be very thankful if anyone could help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try recording a macro while doing what you need in excel UI

Comment: You're looking for the [DateAdd](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dateadd-function-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula approach appears to be correct:

[image]

Using a VBA macro:

```
Sub TimeKonvert()
    Dim d As Date
    For i = 1 To 20
        d = Cells(i, 2).Value
        Cells(i, 3).Value = d + TimeSerial(4, 30, 0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

please note the date rollover in row #7.

**NOTE:**

If you have a working formula and you want VBA to apply it, something like:

```
Sub Konverter2()
    Range("C1:C20").Formula = "=B1+TIME(4,30,0)"
End Sub
```

will also work.

Comment: Thank you so much... I just need "=B1+TIME(4,30,0)" to my coding. helpful. Works good now :)